# Integral identity for variable in integration limit

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The following is an interesting integral identity:

$H(t)=\int_0^tf(x,t)dx$, for $f(x,t)$ a sufficiently smooth function.

Then, $H'(t)=f(t,t)+\int_0^tf_t(x,t)dx$.

Why can't we use standard integration and differentiation to get $H'$ even though a limit of integration is a variable? For example, take $f(x,t)=x+t$. Then, integrating with respect to $x$, using the FTC, then differentiating with respect to $t$, I get $3t$ as a final result, which clearly doesn't agree with the identity. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(t,t)+\int\limits_{0}^{t} f_{t}(x,t)dx=f(t,t)+\int\limits_{0}^{t} 1 dx =2t+t=3t$, which agrees!

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I integrated incorrectly!